# Подскажите удобный Extensions GIT для VS CODE

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-commit, git-push

Всем привет!
Подскажите удобный Extensions GIT для VS CODE.
Условия:

- Commit не всех файлов, а например одного, двух и без предварительного
  перевода остальных измененных файлов в Stash
- Чтобы делал Push вместе
  с Tags
- Чтобы пушить в закрытые, частные репозитории
- Желательно бесплатный, но не обязательно готов заплатить

Comment: 1 - это уже есть в vscode без экстеншнов. Заходите в "Система управления версиями", через + добавляете в индекс гита только изменения в тех файлах, которые нужно закоммитить, коммитите. 3 - аналогично, если в принципе установлен в гит, вы можете пушить в закрытые репозитории (если настроен доступ, например, через ssh ключ). 2 - опишите подробнее что нужно.

Comment: 3 *аналогично, работает в vscode "из коробки", без дополнительных расширений